# python error trying to start IDLE on windows: cannot import name InteractiveInterpreter

Tags: python, python-idle

After installing and playing around with web.py this morning, plus installing (unnecessarily) pysqlite on a Python26 install (Windows) the Idle interface will no longer start.

Error code I receive:

```
C:\Python26>python -m idlelib.idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python26\lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 6, in <module>
    import PyShell
  File "C:\Python26\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 16, in <module>
    from code import InteractiveInterpreter
ImportError: cannot import name InteractiveInterpreter
```

I've tried a few things, including a reinstall of Python 2.6.6. Nothing has restored Idle's ability to run yet.

Anyone have any ideas on what's wrong/how I can fix it?

Comment: Sigh...never mind.

The starter walk-through code for web.py suggested you call your file "code.py". Even though I had this file in my own directory outside of the C:\Python26 folder, it was interfering with the code.py that Python expects (which contains the InteractiveInterpreter code.)

Once I renamed my code.py (to code2.py to test the theory) Idle began working as normal.

Unless this is a cruel joke by the web.py people, I'd suggest that they change what they suggest that you call the example test code name!

Answer (score 1):

Sigh...never mind.

The starter walk-through code for web.py suggested you call your file "code.py". Even though I had this file in my own directory outside of the C:\Python26 folder, it was interfering with the code.py that Python expects (which contains the InteractiveInterpreter code.)

Unless this is a cruel joke by the web.py people, I'd suggest that they change what they suggest that you call the example test code name!